# Page 2+ of taxonomy archives does not recognise sort-order from dropdown

Tags: php, custom-taxonomy, archives, sort, dropdown

I'm using a custom taxonomy archive and I want the user to be able to organise it by 'latest' or 'alphabetical' along with other custom fields in a dropdown form. Seems to be working fine on the first page but on the 2nd page I get

```
NOTICE: wp-content/themes/appchild/taxonomy-mycategory.php:5 - Undefined index: select
require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/themes/appchild/taxonomy-mycategory.php')
```

in my WP-debug tab.

Here is the code for the taxonomy-mycategory.php ...

```
<?php
get_header(); ?>
<?php
$order = "&order=DESC";
if ($_POST['select'] == 'title') { $order = "&order=ASC&orderby=title";  }
if ($_POST['select'] == 'newest') { $order = "&order=DESC"; }
if ($_POST['select'] == 'oldest') { $order = "&order=ASC";  }
if ($_POST['select'] == 'mcommented') { $order = "&order=DESC&orderby=comment_count";  }
if ($_POST['select'] == 'lcommented') { $order = "&order=ASC&orderby=comment_count";  }
$term = get_queried_object();
?>
<section id="primary" class="content-area">
    <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

        <form method="post" id="order">
            Sort things by:
            <select name="select" onchange='this.form.submit()'>
                <option value="title"<?php selected( $_POST['select'],'title', -1 ); ?>>Title</option>
                <option value="newest"<?php selected( $_POST['select'],'newest', -1 ); ?>>Newest</option>
                <option value="oldest"<?php selected( $_POST['select'], 'oldest', -1 ); ?>>Oldest</option>
                <option value="mcommented"<?php selected( $_POST['select'],'mcommented', -1 ); ?>>Most commented</option>
                <option value="lcommented"<?php selected( $_POST['select'],'lcommented' , -1 ); ?>>least commented</option>
            </select>
        </form>

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <header class="page-header">
                <h1 class="page-title">
                    <?php echo $term->name; ?>
                </h1>
                <div class="breadcrumbs">
                    <?php if(function_exists('bcn_display'))
                    {
                        bcn_display();
                    }?>
                </div                    ?>
            </header><!-- .page-header -->


            <?php query_posts($query_string . $order); ?>
            <?php
            // Start the Loop.
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();


                /*
                 * Include the post format-specific template for the content. If you want to
                 * use this in a child theme, then include a file called called content-___.php
                 * (where ___ is the post format) and that will be used instead.
                 */
                get_template_part( 'content', 'mycategory');


            endwhile;

            // Previous/next page navigation.
            twentyfourteen_paging_nav();

        else :
            // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
            get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );

        endif;
        ?>
    </div><!-- #content -->
</section><!-- #primary -->

<?php
get_sidebar( 'content' );
get_sidebar();
get_footer();
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Ah, I get the same error if going on the term archive page with nothing selected in the form

Comment: and also the form itself doesn't retain the selection on page2.. I wonder if this is related.

Comment: Post vars don't get passed to the 2nd page because you're not submitting the form. You also don't do any checks if the post vars exist before trying to read their values.

Comment: "onchange='this.form.submit()" Doesn't this refer to form submission... ?

Comment: Only if you change that form element, but that has nothing to do with your pagination links, or loading the page without submitting the form.

Comment: Aahh ok.. I'll see if I can figure this out.

Comment: Sorted it - I needed to use the _GET function along with a new wp_query.